# How to use custom table for authentication in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-login

I have an existing Customer table and i create model for it

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class Customer(AbstractUser):
        user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  
        username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True) 
        password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
        first_name=models.CharField(max_length=250) 
        last_name=models.CharField(max_length=250)
        email=models.EmailField(max_length=250)
        country=models.CharField(max_length=250) 
        city=models.CharField(max_length=250) 
        zip=models.CharField(max_length=250) 
        state=models.CharField(max_length=250) 
        territory=models.CharField(max_length=250) 
        phone=models.CharField(max_length=15)
        address =models.TextField(blank = True) 
        profile_pic= models.ImageField(upload_to='media/image',default='')
        notes = models.TextField(blank = True) 
        #date_added=models.DateField()
        token=models.CharField(max_length=32)
        is_active= EnumChoiceField(enum_class=ChoiceTypes , default=ChoiceTypes.active)

        class Meta:
            db_table="customer"
```

And also changed default user model in Settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Myapp.Customer'
```

I manually added `last_login, is_superuser, is_active, is_staff, date_joined` columns to Customer table.
I create a super user through command line and the data was inserted into `Customer`  table.
But when i check the login api, it raised some strange error

[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX2Xf.png)

LOGIN VIEW

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.status import (
    HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
    HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
    HTTP_200_OK
)
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def login(request):
    username = request.data.get("username")
    password = request.data.get("password")
    if username is None or password is None:
        return Response({'error': 'Please provide both username and password'}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)


    if not user:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'}, status=HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    return Response({'token': token.key}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

Traceback

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'shoppingcart',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  399.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  61.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  141.         if form.is_valid():

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  185.         return self.is_bound and not self.errors

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in errors
  180.             self.full_clean()

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  382.         self._clean_form()

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_form
  409.             cleaned_data = self.clean()

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in clean
  196.             self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in authenticate
  73.             user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py" in authenticate
  26.             if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in check_password
  111.         return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in check_password
  50.     must_update = hasher_changed or preferred.must_update(encoded)

File "C:\Users\win7.system3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\hashers.py" in must_update
  267.         algorithm, iterations, salt, hash = encoded.split('$', 3)

Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

Also cant login to admin. it shows the same error as shown below

[website login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKZiz.png)

I think tables are created correctly and foreign keys were setup correctly...

[foreign key.. token and customer table....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTBP6.png)

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin 
from .models import Customer
admin.site.register(Customer, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: Please provide your Login View

Comment: I  updated my post

Comment: I've not see that there is nothing wrong with the view yet. Could you also provide the traceback?

Comment: Is this line needed to be changed while using Customer table as authentication table?.......token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user).

Comment: I added traceback

Comment: Sorry for this late. I think that because of your password field inside your Customer model. you could remove it to use the default one from `AbstractBaseUser`. In django, password field will be hashed and store to database so that 32 might not be enough to store the hashed value

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/e1c1eaf0c6f4d3d2f60513d20aa9b84b17d096ec/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L97 Here is how Django handle the saving password process, if you want to reimplement it by yourself then you could reference the flow to make sure that when you authentication, Django could get the hashed value from database and compare with the password from login page